# mobile phone created sd card mounted but not readable. ubuntu studio 22.04.02

Tags: android, sd-card

I formatted a 16gb sd micro card on an MLS mobile phone (that has now gone dead).
I am on ubuntu studio 22.04.02 - dell inspiron laptop.

[image]

the card is mounted but not readable.

sudo parted -l yields:

[image]

(I have copied the contents in /var/tmp/ on a file named "safeplace")

any ideas on how to extract my data from the micro sd?

Comment: Depending on the Android version, the content might have been encrypted based on [file-based encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/file-based) or the older [full-disk encryption](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk).

Comment: thanks. i had a quick look at the links you shared. not sure but i believe android version was <= 8.0. in which case the micro sd card is seen as traditional external storage. i don't know how to decrypt that though. any help?